# React app listning for backend notifications

Tags: node.js, reactjs, notifications, stream

I'm developing a react app and I need to trigger notifications in it for database changes , My back end is node and I'm not sure how to achieve this task.  Should I listen always from front end for back-end notifications?I need to do It like how they do it in Facebook, When I develop my flutter apps I used Firebase streams to achieve this and don't know how to do this in react and node with PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use web sockets or socket.io library.

https://socket.io/

Old browsers don't support web sockets, in that case you need to check repeatedly from the front-end whether there is any notification from the back-end, lets say when database changes. This is called polling.

But, socket.io supports this polling automatically if browser don't support web sockets.

Socket.io is used by many applications . Your purpose seems to be solved using this library. It is event based. Once there is any database change in backend, and if you set up a socket.io event emitter, your front end will receive it via socket.io on the client and your react app can finally notify the user.

From their website,

Socket.IO enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication.
It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing equally on reliability and speed.

Comment: npm install socket.io